# Mongo C# IMongoCollection Design

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using an interface as a collection type when initializing an `IMongoCollection`. I am using an interface class as the collection so that it can be better for testing.

```
public IMongoCollection<IEmployee> Employees => Database.GetCollection<IEmployee>("employee");

public interface IEmployee
{
  [BsonId]
  ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Employee))]
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
  public ObjectId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a database class of `Employee` which implements `IEmployee`. When storing to the database, I have to store a type of `Employee` because I can't declare a new instance of `IEmployee`.

```
var emp = new Employee
{
   Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
   Name = "Wayne Rooney";
};

// Insert into the Employees collection
await Employees.InsertOneAsync(emp);
```

When I want to replace/update that document, I can't because I am querying from a lower layer class of `IEmployee`.

```
await Employees.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(f => f.Id.ToString() == context.Id, g);
```

`context` in this case is the parameter of type `Employee` that I am passing in. `g` is the update document of type `Employee`. `f` in this case is type `IEmployee`. When I do a replace, I get a `[document].Id.ToString() is not supported` error.

So the question is, I'm able to insert and retrieve them, but not able to update/replace/delete a document. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few heads ups.

When inserting to the database, if you have specified an `ObjectId` as your `BsonId` then there is no need to manually set it.

So set the `BsonId`-attribute on your Id.

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then insert as such:

```
var emp = new Employee
{
   Name = "Wayne Rooney";
};

// Insert into the Employees collection
await Employees.InsertOneAsync(emp);
```

A unique `ObjectId` will be set by itself upon inserting.

---

The problem itself most likely lies in the `ToString()`-part of your Linq-query. I'm not sure it translates well into a mongo-query. A quick work-around would be to just use something like:

```
var id = new ObjectId(context.Id);

await Employees.ReplaceOneAsync(f => f.Id == id, g);
```

This eliminates the `ToString()`-call and compares `ObjectId`'s directly.

The support of Linq-queries are somewhat limited in the driver. I would advise against using them (there is also some overhead here).

The suggested, and most direct route is to use the built-in filters.

For instance:

```
var filter = Builders<IEmployee>.Filter
    .Eq(nameof(Employee.Id), new ObjectId(context.Id)); 

await Employees.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, g);
```

`nameof(Employee.Id)` is C# 6, and will return `"Id"`. If you do not have support for C# 6 then simply use `"Id"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One slight problem though. The `Employees` collection is of type `IEmployee`. When I use `Builders<Employee>`, there's a type conflict when passing it in as a parameter into `FindOneAndReplaceAsync`.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Builders<Employee>` to `Builders<IEmployee>`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I'm not able to replace that document with a new one.

Comment: Use `ReplaceOneAsync` instead. `FindOneAndReplaceAsync` finds one, replaces it, and returns it. Also, are you sure `Context.Id` is properly set, and is the correct id?

Comment: I've confirmed and it's properly set and is the correct id.

Comment: Then it should be replacing. Might be related to the fact that the collection has an interface as type parameter. Try changing `IMongoCollection<IEmployee>` to `IMongoCollection<Employee>`.

Comment: Yea, I'm thinking the same. I've tried `IMongoCollection<Employee>` in the past. It worked just fine. But now I'm changing to `IMongoCollection<IEmployee>` and ran into this issue.

Comment: Then there is your issue. Seems as if interfaces are not supported for strongly typed collections. Edit: this is most likely do to the fact that there is no way to initialize a new instance of an interface, which `FindOne[...]Async` most likely requires. I would've guessed that it would throw an exception though.

Comment: You may be correct, though I need to confirm with Mongo if it is supported or not. Thanks for your help! **Edit:** The only exception it's throwing is `[document].Id is not supported` or any property of `IEmployee`.

Comment: And that's because of the aforementioned reason. :)